# org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation in java spring boot

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, events, event-handling

I am developing chat application using java springboot and Angular 7. I am using events in spring boot and angular. I am trying to generate events in spring boot for angular to listen the event. However, I am getting following error:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation]
```

Here is my controller code in springboot:

```
@CrossOrigin("*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/chat")
public class MessageController {

@Autowired
MessageService messageService;

@Autowired
private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageController.class);

@PostMapping(consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public GenericApiResponse<Map<String, Object>>message(@RequestBody MessageRequest req) {
    logger.info("MessageController:: messagemethod [POST] /chat");
    GenericApiResponse<Map<String, Object>> responseObj = new GenericApiResponse<>();
    Object returnValue = new Object();
    try {
        returnValue = messageService.translateText(req);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("EXCEPTION: "+e.getStackTrace().toString());
        responseObj.setStatus(Constants.ERROR);
        responseObj.setMessage("Internal Server Error");
    }
    Map<String, Object> resMap = new HashMap<>();
    resMap.put("result", returnValue);
    resMap.put("sender", req.getSender());
    responseObj.setResponseObject(resMap);
    responseObj.setStatus(Constants.SUCCESS);

    MessageEvent messageEvent = new MessageEvent(this,"eventName", responseObj);
    applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(messageEvent);

    return responseObj;
}
```

I am unable to figure out what is the issue and how to solve it. Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you please try my suggestions. It should fix the problem you are facing.

Comment: Please share CURL of your request. I would like to observe the headers as well.

Comment: `curl -X POST \ http://localhost:8090/chat\ -H 'Accept: */*' \ -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \ -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \ -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \ -H 'Content-Length: 134' \ -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \ -H 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=349102FC07B387A5D2629995D508210F' \ -H 'Host: localhost:8090' \ -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \ -d '{ "text" : "I can do this now", "sourceLanguageCode" : "en", "targetLanguageCode" : "hi", "sender" : "abc" }`

Comment: can you check your jackson dependencies are in place for backend?

Comment: I am not using jackson dependency

Answer (score 0):

From first look at your code, I can observe following problems:

1. `@ResponseBody` is added but no response is returned i.e. method type is void.
2. `produces = "application/json"` doesn't make sense for a void method returning no response.

Hence, for a rest endpoint always return some response. You can fix it by putting following as return statement in the end in your method:

```
return ResponseEntity.ok("your message");
```

Also, `@ResponseBody` means that response is always serialized to json hence, no need to specify `, produces = "application/json"` explicitly.

**Update:**

Can you please also try replacing `consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json"` with

```
  consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
  produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
```

And

ensure that request headers are set to `application/json`.

Also, ensrue jackson dependencies are in place.

Comment: Hi, now I am returning the responseObj, so added GenericApiResponse<Map<String, Object>> as return type. And therefore I am keeping produces= "application/json" as it is. But still it is giving me same error

Comment: what's the error? did you try removing `@ResponseBody` in this case?

Comment: Also, can you share what is the request you are making?

Comment: Yes, I have removed `@ResponseBody` as I am keeping `produces= "application/json"`. My request body contains: sender and text.

Comment: I have suggested one more change. Please try that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: `EventSource` in angular takes `Content-Type : text/event-stream` by default. So I created new method and added `@RequestHeader(value = "Content-Type", defaultValue = "text/event-stream")` as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic conversion of Objects are neglected if you don't have getter method for the return type object. If you don't have getter method for `GenericApiResponse` object add one.